# Exact Category of SPFx

Tags: sharepoint-addin, share

Is SharePoint Framework (SPFx) comes to fill the gap of SharePoint add-ins and JavaScript injection, or we use SPFx as a library when we create solution using JSOM and SCOM??? what is the exact category of SPFx?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this 30 minute YouTube video will answer your questions.

[SharePoint Framework Training - Getting Started with the SharePoint Framework](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Pt5cnU4MpU&list=PLR9nK3mnD-OV-RPXQ3Lco845qoEy7VJoc)